# Showing when the permutation representation is faithful

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, functions, representation-theory

My objective is to show when the permutation representation is faithful. The below is my intent. I would be grateful if someone can see if it looks correct or if I have misunderstood something.

Let $G$ be a group that acts on a set $S$ from the left, i.e., there exists a multiplication $G\times S\rightarrow S$ which is associative and such that $es=s$, with $s\in S$ and $e$ being the identity in $G$. We construct *the permutation representation* $\rho :G\rightarrow GL_n$ by defining a vector space $V$ by the span of the natural basis $\{\boldsymbol{e}_s\}_{s\in S}$ and then define each matrix $\rho(g)$, by
$$\tag{1}
\rho(g)\boldsymbol{e}_s:=\boldsymbol{e}_{gs},
$$
and extend linearly:
$$\tag{2}
\rho(g)\sum_{s\in S}a_s\boldsymbol{e}_s=\sum_{s\in S}a_s\rho(g)\boldsymbol{e}_s.
$$
The representation is faithful if $\forall g,h\in G :\rho(g)=\rho(h)\Longrightarrow g=h$, so assume that $\rho(g)=\rho(h)$ for arbitrary $g,h\in G$. Then
$$\tag{3}
\boldsymbol{e}_{gs}=X(g)\boldsymbol{e}_s=X(h)\boldsymbol{e}_s=\boldsymbol{e}_{hs},
$$
for any $s\in S$. Since $\{\boldsymbol{e}_s\}_{s\in S}$ is a basis, Equation $(3)$ tells us that $gs=hs$ for all $s\in S$. It follows that $\rho$ is faithful if
$$
\bigg(\bigwedge_{s\in S}gs=hs\bigg)\implies g=h.
$$

Comment: The permutation representation is faithful if and only if the action of $G$ on $S$ is faithful, which I think is essentially what you have written.

Comment: This question is almost identical to a question you asked previously and then deleted. Why? https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:DyEgrHope1sJ:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4742706/showing-that-the-permutation-representation-is-faithful&cd=11&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk